# Python + cmd line string manipulation what should I have done diferently

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I am pretty new to programming in general and watching CTF videos has inspired me to start out with python and having a good grasp on the command line (I am on OSX btw).
In the past I used anaconda's spyder environment for school (Python 2.7).
As I was setting up brew, pip and python I realized I had a bunch of packages from Anaconda for 2.7 on pip but none for 3.6 on pip3.
I decided to `pip list` and got a table of all the (many) packages anaconda installed for me.
This is what you get :

```
    Package                            Version                
---------------------------------- -----------------------
alabaster                          0.7.10                 
anaconda-client                    1.6.5                  
anaconda-navigator                 1.6.8                  
anaconda-project                   0.8.0                  
appnope                            0.1.0                  
appscript                          1.0.1                  
asn1crypto                         0.22.0                 
astroid                            1.5.3                  
astropy                            2.0.2                  
Babel                              2.5.0                  
backports-abc                      0.5                    
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.4                    
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0                  
backports.ssl-match-hostname       3.5.0.1                
beautifulsoup4                     4.6.0                  
bitarray                           0.8.1    
...
```

I then had the idea:
Can I convert this text to a string in this format.
"Package1 Package2 Package3 Package4" so I can pip3 all the packages.
**This became a string manipulation challenge as I realized it probably isn't effective to just pip3 install 150+ packages and faster to just download anaconda for 3.7.(Compatibility, useless, time consuming...)**

So i started by extracting the list with ">" in the terminal to a new file I made
 I then removed the first two lines with the tail function in the terminal.
What could I have done with python I tried many things but it never worked and found this which killed all motivation to debug/think.

```
tail -n +2 "$FILE" > "$FILE.tmp" && mv "$FILE.tmp" "$FILE"
```

After that I made this simple python script to convert to the format I was looking for by removing all the versions and making them one single string.

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
    new_string=''
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i]=lines[i].split(" ", 1)
        del lines[i][1]
        new_string += lines[i][0] + ' '


    print new_string
```

Please let me know if there is anything I could have done in the terminal window or why my python script is bad.
My for loop IMO seems kind of bizarre with the `i` and the `lines[i][0]` is ugly IMO because you don't naturally grasp what it means.

Any help or different  method would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance.

**TLDR:
Any insight on:

1)simple way to remove n first lines of a txt file with python or terminal

2)Why is my Python code ugly , is there a terminal equivalent??**

Answer (score 0):

> simple way to remove n first lines of a txt file with python or
>   terminal

This will open your file, and save all the lines after n lines to a new file.

```
lines = open('textfile.txt').readlines()
open('newfile.txt', 'w').writelines(lines[n:])
```

---

> How can I 'prettify' this Python code:

```
with open("file.txt","r+") as f:
lines=f.readlines()
new_string=''
for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i]=lines[i].split(" ", 1)
    del lines[i][1]
    new_string += lines[i][0] + ' '
```

This can be written as:
(iterate through the list *lines* and save them all into one string afterwards if you'd wish.)

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    # You can actually process the file line by line without saving it into a list:
    for line in f:
        # For clearer code, you can index the split function here:
        line = line.split(' ', 1)[0]
        lines.append(line)
```

Please read the commentation on my code for explanation. I think it would benefit you to read up on the docs here about for-loops in python [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one line shell command that would do what you want (install all pip package with pip3, if I intepret correctly)

```
pip list | awk 'NR>2' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs pip3 install
```

`awk 'NR>2'` will take `pip list` input and start from 3rd line, `awk '{print $1}'` will print the package name, and finally `xargs` will take in each package name and install the package. Try running it with `pip` instead of `pip3` to see all the `Requirement already satisfied` to verify that this works.